# Getting a Camera actor in event graph

Tags: camera, unreal-engine5

I am developing a simulation in UE5. I have a first person character with its usual camera and then I have another camera as a child actor of a piece of machinery. With this camera I want to orbit about the machine so that the user can view the machine from all angles. I am using the EnhancedInputSystem and mapped the F10 key to the IA_CameraSwitch input action. I am trying to do something like in the following diagram:

[image]

I can drag the firstpersoncamera into the event graph, but I cannot locate the second Camera Actor to place it in the event graph. I tried to search for it and tried to drag it in from the Outliner, but no success.

Is this possible to do? What am I doing wrong? Must the second camera also be a child actor of the first person? I ultimately want to have multiple pieces of machinery, each with their own camera or am I missing the plot completely here.